# How to Derive the Minimum Time for $⟨ψ_0|A(t)|ψ_0⟩$ to Vanish Using Uncertainty Principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hamiltonian, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I am trying to work through some bookwork, and I am stuck on the titular question. The scenario is as follows:

In a generic finite dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, define the operator $A(t) ≡ U^{\dagger}(t)AU(t)$ with $U(t) = e^{−itH}$ and both $A$ and $H$ self-adjoint.

I computed the operator $\frac{\partial A(t)}{\partial t} = i[H, A(t)]$, which I hope is correct.

Now I am supposing we have some state $|ψ_0⟩$ and define the operator $A$ to be the projector to the $t = 0$ subspace spanned by the starting quantum state, and determine the minimal time $t$ it takes for $⟨ψ_0|A(t)|ψ_0⟩$ to vanish.

My understanding of this is that I would define $A = |ψ_0⟩⟨ψ_0|$ to be the projector (again, hopefully correct).

From here, hints mention using the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle: $$\Delta H\Delta A(t) \geq \frac{⟨ψ_0|[H, A(t)]|ψ_0⟩}{2}$$ but I am a bit unsure on how to do this. I see the derivative operator (the commutator) is present, but I don't see how to make a conclusion on the expectation value of the projector...

Any advice how to proceed? And verify my workings to this point are correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are asked to find the minimum time at which $\langle \psi_0 | A(t) | \psi_0 \rangle$ vanishes. To do this, first you consider what values this object can take on to begin with.
$$\begin{align}
\langle \psi_0 | A(t) | \psi_0 \rangle = \langle \psi_0 | U^{\dagger}(t) A U(t) |\psi_0 \rangle \\ 
=\langle \psi_0|e^{iHt}(|\psi_0\rangle\langle\psi_0|)e^{-iHt}| \psi_0\rangle\\
= ||\langle\psi_0|e^{-iHt}|\psi_0\rangle||^2 \\
\geq 0
\end{align}$$
So as can be seen, since the *minimum* value this object takes on is $0$, you can take the derivative of this object to look for the time at which it vanishes.

Comment: So if I was to take the partial derivatives with respect to $t$, I end up with $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \langle \psi_0 |A(t) |\psi_0 \rangle \right) =  \langle \psi_0 |\partial_t A(t) |\psi_0 \rangle =  \langle \psi_0 |i[H, A(t)] |\psi_0 \rangle$ and then I can invoke uncertainty principle to state that this is $\geq 2\Delta H \Delta A(t)$? I'm just not entirely sure how I am to manipulate this into a situation where I can solve for $t$...